# Dúvida em strcmp

Tags: c

Estou em dúvida em uma linha de código:

```
if(strcmp(novo->nome,aux->nome)>=0)
```

Como ocorre sua comparação? Sendo que o nome é um char!

Comment: Sendo `nome` um char, essa instrucao tem erro. Com o `#include <string.h>` o compilador detecta o erro e avisa o programador.

Comment: @pmg erro porquê?

Comment: @JorgeB.: Erro porque o tipo `char` não é compativel com o tipo `char *`. A função `strcmp()` compara o conteúdo de dois ponteiros; não o valor de dois caracteres.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O método strcmp testa a igualdade das Strings.

1. Retorna um número negativo se string1 for menor que string2;
2. Retorna zero se as duas strings são iguais;
3. Retorna um número positivo se string1 é maior que string2.

A declaração do método é a seguinte:

```
int strcmp ( const char * str1, const char * str2 );
```

Sendo assim, retorna um inteiro.

Logo, em seu código, vai entrar no escopo do if quando `novo->nome` for igual ou maior a `aux->nome`